# Changing the value in data set using PROC SCORE using SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm New to SAS Please can one help me how to change the value of data set using PROC SCORE. I have two data set as shown below image how to append the label value from data set 2 to set 1.

**If gender is 1 We should append the value as M from the set 2**

[image: data set image]

Comment: You need more than just proc score. But Proc format and score will get you there. See this paper on how to create a format and you can then apply it to your data set. https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/001-30.pdf

Comment: FYI-please post data as text not images. If we were to try and generate working code we'd have to type out your data.

Comment: Please edit your question if you'd like to add data. However, the comment above really should answer your question.

Comment: What does PROC SCORE have to do with the question?

Comment: @Tom This is a basic example, we have a different use case in mapping two data sets... we cant hard code the values as such like that

Comment: Please explain the rule for how to determine that 1 means "M". Does 0 mean "F"? What value(s) should map to "O"?

Answer (score 1):

SAS uses formats as the way to display values in human friendly ways.  Looks like you want to convert your second table into a format definition so that you can attach that format to the GENDER variable in your first dataset.

From the description it sounds like you want to generate a custom format like this:

```
 proc format ;
   value gender 1='M' 0='F' other='O' ;
 run;
```

You could then use a FORMAT statement, inside your `Proc SCORE` step, to associate the custom format to your `GENDER` variable.

```
 format gender gender. ;
```

It is possible to build a format from a dataset, but you have not described any way to match the values of 0 and 1 in the first dataset to the values M or F in the second dataset.  What was the logic for deciding that 1 should be mapped to M?  Is it because M is first in the table? Is it because F comes before M in the alphabet and 0 comes before 1 in numeric ordering?

Comment: The above answer is straight forward I want to map the value from the second data set only...The scenario is that value should be taken from the data set only it shouldn't be hardcode @tom